# How to evaluate the integral $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int \limits_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{q^{-s}x^sds}{s(1-q^{-s})}\text{?}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I now that poles are at $s=\frac{2k\pi i}{\log q}, k\in \mathbb{Z}$. I think that when $k=0$ the pole at $s=0$ is of order 2. When $k \neq 0$, I can find the residue, but when $s=0$, I'm really stuck. Thanks.

Comment: $\frac1{1-q^{-s}} = \frac1{s \log q + (s\log q)^2+O(s^3)} = \frac1{s\log q} (1-s \log q +O(s^2))$

Comment: $s=0$ is a branch point. You cannot use the residue theorem without making the integrand a single-valued function, i.e. in your case - without imposing cuts in the complex plane

Comment: Is $q$ a real number?

Comment: @Svyatoslav $x^s = e^{s \ln x}$, the integrand is a meromorphic function of $s$. If we don't have to show that the integral converges, we can start with $F(s) = \mathcal L\big[ x \mapsto \lfloor x \rfloor \big](s)$, then we know that the p.v. integral of $F(s) e^{x s}/(2 \pi i)$ converges to $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for $x \in \mathbb R^+ \setminus \mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes, q is real number @FShrike

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this integral important to you?

Comment: Wait a second... is $x$ also real?

Comment: @Maxim, yes, you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $q>0$

$$\mathcal{M}_x\left[\theta\left(x-q^n\right)\right](-s)=\int\limits_0^\infty \theta\left(x-q^n\right)\,x^{-s-1}\,ds=\frac{1}{s}\, q^{-n s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{1}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{s}\, \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty q^{-n s}=\frac{1}{s \left(q^s-1\right)}=\frac{q^{-s}}{s \left(1-q^{-s}\right)}=F_q(s)\tag{2}$$

so

$$f_q(x)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}[F_q(s)]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{q^{-s}}{s \left(1-q^{-s}\right)}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ $$=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \frac{q^{-s}}{s \left(1-q^{-s}\right)}\, x^s\,ds\tag{3}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \theta\left(x-q^n\right)$$

which seems to make more sense for $q>1$ verus the original assumption of $q>0$ above.

---

Now as an example consider the case $q=2$ where

$$f_2(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \theta\left(x-2^n\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \theta\left(x-2^n\right){\tag4}$$

and

$$F_2(s)=\frac{2^{-s}}{s \left(1-2^{-s}\right)}=\frac{1}{s \left(2^s-1\right)}.\tag{5}$$

---

The explicit formula

$$\tilde{f}_2(x)=\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{f_2(x-\epsilon)+f_2(x+\epsilon)}{2}\right)$$ $$=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \left(\frac{i x^{-\frac{2 i \pi k}{\log (2)}}}{2 \pi k}-\frac{i x^{\frac{2 i \pi k}{\log (2)}}}{2 \pi k}\right)\right)\tag{6}$$

derived from the residues of $F_2(s)\,x^s$ at $s=\frac{2 i \pi k}{\log(2)}$ simplifies to

$$\tilde{f}_2(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k \log(x)}{\log (2)}\right)}{k}\right)\tag{7}$$

and has the closed form representation

$$\tilde{f}_2(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \left(\log\left(1-x^{\frac{2 i \pi}{\log(2)}}\right)-\log\left(1-x^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{\log(2)}}\right)\right)}{2 \pi}.\tag{8}$$

---

Formulas (6) to (8) for $\tilde{f}(x)$ above are all valid for $x>1$ which is illustrated in Figure (1) below where formula (6) is evaluated at $K=50$.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (6) and (8) overlaid on formula (4)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formulas (6) and (8) for $\tilde{f}_2(x)$ in orange and green overlaid on formula (4) for $f_2(x)$ in blue

Comment: If you mean that the integral of $F_2(s) x^s$ gives $\tilde f_{\! 2}(x)$ for all $x > 1$, then, strictly speaking, that's not correct, the improper integral $\int_{c - i \infty}^{c + i \infty}$ diverges for $x = 2$. (The integral can be split into a part which is convergent by Dirichlet's test and a divergent part. If we can show that the integrals over large semicircles tend to zero -- taking care to take semicircles avoiding the poles -- then divergence also follows from the fact that the sum of the residues diverges.) The p.v. integral exists.

Comment: @Maxim Do you mean the sum of the residues diverges near transitions similar to the Gibbs phenomenon for Fourier series?

Comment: I'm considering $x = 2$. The residue $r_k$ at $s = 2 \pi k i/\ln 2$ is equal to $1/(2 \pi k i)$ if $k \neq 0$ and $1/2$ if $k = 0$. The sum $\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty r_k$, which, by definition, is equal to $\lim_{(m, n) \to (-\infty, \infty)} \sum_{k = m}^n r_k$, diverges. (Also, before analyzing the integrals over large semicircles, we cannot say anything about how the sum is related to the original integral.)

Comment: @Maxim Note formula (7) above for $\tilde{f}_2(x)$ converges exactly to $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=2$ as expected since at $x=2$ the $\sin$ term in the sum over $k$ evaluates to $0$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Maxim I believe you need to evaluate the sum as $f_2(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K r_k(x)\right)$ which is consistent with the conditional convergence requirement of the residue formula for the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$ for example. Formulas (6) and (7) in my answer above are equivalent, so using formula (6) above $\tilde{f}_2(2)=\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi k i}+\frac{1}{2 π (−k) i)}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K0\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Maxim Formulas (6) and (7) above are essentially well-known formulas for $\lfloor y\rfloor$ evaluated at $y=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}=\log_2(x)$, and I believe the closed form illustrated in formula (8) evaluates exactly correct for all $x>1$ (except it's indeterminate at the discontinuities of $f_2(x)$ which occur at $x=2^m$ where $m$ is an integer).